# Provisioning a Virtual Server with 1TB HDD

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I need to provision a server through API with the configuration of
RAM:16GB,
OS: Centos5.6 Quad Core 64 bit,
HDD:1TB.

API request which I used
      https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest/createObject.json

Request Post data:

```
{"parameters":[{"hostname":"jmblw","domain":"micron.com","startCpus":4,"maxMemory":16,"blockDevices":[{"device":0,"diskImage":{"capacity":100}},{"device":2,"diskImage":{"capacity":1000}}],"hourlyBillingFlag":true,"localDiskFlag":true,"operatingSystemReferenceCode":"CENTOS_5_64","datacenter":{"name":"sng01"}}]}
```

RESPONSE :

```
{
"error": "Unable to find a price for block device 2.",
"code": "SoftLayer_Exception_NotFound"
}
```

Can you please tell me how I can povision a server with HDD 1 TB. and please send me the Request body post data's structure

Comment: i would try to change device":2,  to device":1, , you have a device id 0 and 2 specified, but not 1...  or try 1 and 2. but not 0 and 2

Comment: If im trying with device : 1   it showing error response RESPONSE:
{
"error": "Invalid value provided for 'blockDevices.device'. Block device 1 is reserved for the SWAP disk.",
"code": "SoftLayer_Exception_InvalidValue"
}

Comment: oh, that explains it. nvm me

Answer (score 0):

SAN disks have the configuration capacity  for 1TB (for second disk) but "Local" disks have a 300GB as maximum. If we change "localDiskFlag": true to “false”, the request should work.

Please try the following:

```
https://[usename]:[apikey]@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest/createObject.json
```

Method: POST

Json:

```
{
  "parameters": [
    {
      "hostname": "jmblw",
      "domain": "micron.com",
      "startCpus": 4,
      "maxMemory": 16,
      "blockDevices": [
        {
          "device": 0,
          "diskImage": {
            "capacity": 100
          }
        },
        {
          "device": 2,
          "diskImage": {
            "capacity": 1000
          }
        }
      ],
      "hourlyBillingFlag": true,
      "localDiskFlag": false,
      "operatingSystemReferenceCode": "CENTOS_5_64",
      "datacenter": {
        "name": "sng01"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```